# What's the rationale for using insertion sort over shell sort in Array.sort in V8

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, v8

V8 uses quick-sort for arrays of the length over 10 elements, and insertion sort for arrays less than that. Here is [the sources](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/js/array.js#L708):

```
function InnerArraySort(array, length, comparefn) {
  // In-place QuickSort algorithm.
  // For short (length <= 10) arrays, insertion sort is used for efficiency.
```

I'm wondering what's the rationale for not using shell-sort instead of an insertion sort? I understand that it probably doesn't make a difference for an array of 10 elements, but still. Any ideas?

Comment: Apparently it *does* make enough of a performance difference for small arrays to include that switch.

Comment: @Bergi, yes, `insertion sort` is better on small arrays than `quick sort`, but `shell sort` is better then `insertion sort` on the small arrays

Comment: Afaik shell sort is not much different than insertion sort, but if you think it's a worthwhile change and can write a realistic benchmark I'm sure the V8 team will be happy about a patch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original rationale is lost to history; the [commit](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/b4a40eb22f07ef1707d56a9dfa49c024127a5add) that introduced InsertionSort for short arrays (all the way back in 2008) only mentions that it's faster than QuickSort (for such short arrays). So it boils down to: someone implemented it that way, and nobody else saw a reason to change it since.

Since InsertionSort is known to be very efficient for short arrays, I agree that changing it probably doesn't make a difference -- and there are lots of things for the team to work on that actually do make a difference.

Comment: thanks, so what you're saying is that probably somebody implemented `insertion sort` and there was to reason to consider changing it to shell-sort?

Comment: Yes. It used to be QuickSort only, then the InsertionSort case for small arrays was added, and apparently since then it's been "good enough".

Answer (score 1):

Great question. The rationale is simple, it is actually faster to use insertion sort on those small arrays, at least typically. Java in fact made the same switch a long while ago. Now they do insertion sort if the array is less than 7 long in their code. See [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java). It is under the function sort1 at the top.

Basically what happens (in most cases) for such small arrays is that the overhead for Quicksort makes it slower than insertion sort. Insertion sort in these cases is much more likely to approach it's best performance at O(n) while Quicksort is still likely to stay at O(n log n).

Shell sort on the other hand tends to be much slower than insertion sort. That being said, it can be much faster (relativly). The best case for insertion sort is still 0(n), whereas the best case for shell sort is O(n log n). All number under ten then should have the potential for being faster from a mathematical standpoint. Unfortunately for shell sort, there is a lot more swapping involved. Shell sort then can become much slower. Insertion sort tends to be able to pull off swapping with O(1) swaps, whereas Shell sort is likely to be around O(n) swaps. Swaps are costly in machines because they tend to end up using a third temp register for swapping (there are ways of using XOR, but that is still three commands on the CPU, typically). Therefore, insertion sort still wins on an actual machine, typically.

Comment: thanks for the link and info, but the question is about shell sort vs insertion sort, not quick-sort.

Comment: Sorry I missed that, hope this answers it better.